# nginx log http status what is 404 187

Tags: http, logging, nginx

Hi I got nginx access log file like the follows:

```
192.168.1.1 - - [06/Nov/2012:22:13:46 +1100] "GET /?i=a HTTP/1.1" 404 187 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1"
192.168.1.2 - - [06/Nov/2012:22:13:50 +1100] "GET /?i=b HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "http://abc.com/545512565475443/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4"
```

So that `404` in the first line should be not found and `200` in the second line means success. That's okay, but what is the `187` behind `404` in the first line and `0` behind `200` in the second line?

thanks,
Green

Answer (score 7, accepted):

according to [this](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLogModule)
default log format is:

```
log_format combined '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  '
                    '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
```

so 187 or 0 after the response code is number of bytes sent to client